# Call to a member function getId() on a non-object /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241)

Tags: magento

I know usually "call to a member function" error is because of the object's class doesn't extend the appropriate parent class. However, my NS_Module_Block_File class has already extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View. My code in file.phtml:

```
$object = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
$_product = $object->loadByAttribute('sku','P01');
$id = $_product->getId();
```

I've also have put this in my theme's local.xml:

```
<ns_module_file_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="ns_module/file" name="module.file" template="file.phtml" />
    </reference>
</ns_module_file_index>
```

I'm not sure where the problem is. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the method for loadByAttribute:

```
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the product with the sku "P01" doesn't exist, the object won't be returned as the collection is empty; false will be returned instead.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. It seems the numeric SKUs causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','P01');
```

Comment: Thanks. Got the same thing. Besides, because it's an iteration for thousands of SKUs, I've to use getSingleton instead.